# Meaning of Horizon Zero Dawn audio datapoint

Tags: video-games, horizon-zero-dawn

In the game Horizon Zero Dawn, there is an audio datapoint that says

> Horizon Zero Dawn :
>
> Secure com EVZD-XX1X011X
>
> Audio Datapoints:
>
> Elizabet Sobeck:Yes.if we’d had even one day less...

What’s is she referring to?

It's located on the fourth floor, in a room just beyond the Deathbringer boss chamber:IGN

Comment: It would likely be useful to add more information about when this datapoint happens in the game, for example 'After level 3'.

Comment: I've played the game and, usually, datapoints are tied to other datapoints in the nearby area. Maybe you can extract some meaning/context by exploring the area to find more datapoints (assuming that you haven't already done this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spoilers for the plot of Horizon Zero Dawn:

> She is referring to the very narrow success of Operation Enduring Victory in holding off the Faro Plague for just long enough to complete the Zero Dawn project and bring Gaia fully online. If they’d had even one day less then the project would have failed and life on Earth would never have been reborn.

The full quote is:

> GENERAL HERRES: Dr. Sobeck. As projected, the Wichita salient has collapsed. Five horus-class Titans have broken through. We predict contact in 34 hours.
> ELISABET SOBECK: Everything is in position, General. It took a few shortcuts to pull everything together, but Zero Dawn is functionally complete. Good to go. 
> GENERAL HERRES: Then Enduring Victory served its purpose, after all.
> ELISABET SOBECK: Yes. If we'd had even one day less...

Comment: The “we’d” its “we did” ,”we would” or “we should”?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley In this context, it’s clearly “we had”, as in “If we had had even one day less”. It’s the past perfect tense of “have”, complicated by the fact that the past perfect also uses “have” in its construction so you end up using it twice.